# Opera mini 6 showing zoomed view (same on mobile view ON option)?

Tags: php, javascript, mobile-website

I have used javascript code which you can see below:
I don't know why only opera mini 6 (at all types of mobiles) showing zoomed view? specially my site.
site is www.propertiesng.com/mobile

Please help.

// Check if the UA is a mobile one (iphone, ipod, android, blackberry)
        isUAMobile =!!(agent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|blackberry|android 0.5|htc|lg|midp|mmp|mobile|nokia|opera mini|palm|pocket|psp|sgh|smartphone|symbian|treo mini|Playstation Portable|SonyEricsson|Samsung|MobileExplorer|PalmSource|Benq|Windows Phone|Windows Mobile|IEMobile|Windows CE|Nintendo Wii|maemo|presto|mini)/i));

Answer (score 0):

try changing your doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

Comment: Solved! =)

I used this

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: weird, mobile doc type should have fixed but as long as you found your solution it doesn't matter